# Integer solutions to $ax^2+by^2=1$

Tags: number-theory

I'm looking for methods to determine integer solutions to $ax^2+by^2=1$.
In particular, I'm would like to determine the integer solutions to $81x^2-243y^2=1$.
Any hints in the right direction are appreciated.

Comment: Left side is divisible by $3$, right side is not.

Comment: what was I thinking! Thanks. How about the general case?

Comment: Are a and b integers? Rational?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a finite sequence of steps to reduce (in the sense of Lagrange and Gauss) an indefinite form. Once that is accomplished, the method of neighboring forms shows whether $1$ is represented, as well as whether $-1$ is represented. It is a theorem of Lagrange that every primitively represented number occurs as the first coefficient in one of the forms in the cycle. In this example, we see it as the first coefficient in line 4, or the third coefficient in line 3. There are related methods for finding all solutions, one thing at a time.

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle 5 0 -41

  0  form              5           0         -41  delta      0
  1  form            -41           0           5  delta      2
  2  form              5          20         -21


          -1          -2
           0          -1

To Return  
          -1           2
           0          -1

0  form   5 20 -21   delta  -1     ambiguous  
1  form   -21 22 4   delta  6
2  form   4 26 -9   delta  -3
3  form   -9 28 1   delta  28
4  form   1 28 -9   delta  -3     ambiguous  
5  form   -9 26 4   delta  6
6  form   4 22 -21   delta  -1
7  form   -21 20 5   delta  4
8  form   5 20 -21


  form   5 x^2  + 20 x y  -21 y^2 

minimum was   1rep   x = 19   y = 22 disc 820 dSqrt 28  M_Ratio  31.36
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
11969  58212
13860  67409
=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

Why not... given (positive) prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ there is guaranteed to be a solution to $p x^2 - y^2 = 1.$ Given another prime $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ mutual nonresidues, that is Legendre $(p|q)= (q|p) = -1,$ there is a solution to $p x^2 - q y^2 = 1.$ From the example above, note that there is no solution to $41 x^2 - 5 y^2 = 1.$